# How to check if checkboxes are checked in an image with python?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

I have an image with some text, a table with checkboxes and then again a text as shown in the following
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5wrw.jpg).

I would like to write a python script that scans the image and checks witch checkbox is checked and write the result into a variable. Do you have any suggestions or advice on how to do this?

So far I've used pytesseract to exctract all the text in the image returning everything except the content of the table. Next, I've tried cv2 but could only modify the image itself. I was able to erase everything except the table structure. However I also lost the content inside the table.

My current thought is, ideally I'm able to convert the table into a 2D list and then use a "for each loop" to iterate over them. But at the moment I have no idea how to do it and I would appreciate any suggestions to push me into the right direction. Any advice would be appreciated :).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Invert your image so that the lines are white on a black background. Then threshold and get the contours. Filter the contours on size and shape. Find all the small squares. Check the number of white pixels inside each of those squares. Find the ones that have the most number of white pixels.

Comment: Hello, I kind of expected that my question doesn't really fit to stack overflow since I don't have an error with my code but I'm asking for advice. 

I appreciate your advice! I like the idea to check the pixels inside the square. I think I also found a blog post on how to write processed image into a csv. file. I'm currently trying to understand that post :D. Thanks for your help :)